# SQL average money spent per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get some help in writing SQL query for the table below. The table represents how much students spent at a food court on a given date. With this table, write an SQL query that calculates the number of days between the
first and last date of money spent by each student and the money spent per day in this timespan.

```
Student_id            Date      Money Spent($)
    1              01.01.2017      15.13
    2              03.01.2017      22.94
    3              03.01.2017      37.50
    2              01.02.2017      44.26
    2              08.04.2017      52.62
    3              09.08.2017      34.67
    1              02.09.2017      43.87
    3              04.11.2017      12.67
```

Comment: Please check here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2908599

Comment: What have you tried so far? With home work questions it is particularly mportant that we do not write the whole solution from scratch because you are not going to learn from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Student_id,MIN([date]) mindate, MAX([date]) maxdate,SUM(MoneySpent) TotalSpent,
        SUM(MoneySpent)/DATEDIFF ( MIN([date]) , MAX([date]) ) MoneySpentPerDay 
        FROM StudentExpenses
        GROUP BY Student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT student_id,AVG(spent) FROM `students` GROUP BY student_id;
```